# Rails multi_db with transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've recently installed the multi_db gem on my rails 2.3.10 app in order to use a MySql master/slave replication.

since installing the gem, every time I use transactions in my code , e.g.:

`MyModel.connection.transaction do
...some code...
end`

I get an exception: `NoMethodError undefined method 'assert_valid_keys' for true:TrueClass`

any ideas on how to use multi_db with transactions?

EDIT: 
iv'e found something interesting, ever since i've installed multi_db

```
MyModel.connection.transaction do
  test = 1+2
end
```

return the following exception (in most cases): `NoMethodError undefined method 'assert_valid_keys' for true:TrueClass`

but if i run:

```
MyModel.connection.transaction({}) do
  test = 1+2
end
```

everything runs smoothly.

my gut filling tells me that multi_db (which is based on masochism gem) doesnt "play nice" with one of the other gems im using ( maybe: deadlock_retry or ar-extensions).

any ideas?

Comment: since assert_valid_keys is defined on Hash, I guess that you are doing something wrong within your code. it might help posting a snippet here

Comment: iv'e found something interesting, ever since i've installed multi_db

MyModel.connection.transaction do
  test = 1+2
end

return the following exception (in most cases): ` NoMethodError undefined method 'assert_valid_keys' for true:TrueClass `

but if i run:

MyModel.connection.transaction({}) do
  test = 1+2
end

everything runs smoothly.

my gut filling tells me that multi_db (which is based on masochism gem) doesnt "play nice" with one of the other gems im using ( maybe: deadlock_retry or ar-extensions).

any ideas?

Comment: Here's your stack trace from the duplicate question, for reference: http://pastie.org/3063822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multi_db is not entirely compatible with ActiveRecord 2.3.10. It's calling the `transaction` method on the connection with different arguments than are acceptable (see [the call site](https://github.com/schoefmax/multi_db/blob/master/lib/multi_db/connection_proxy.rb#L139) here).

You'll have to either not use transactions, downgrade Rails, fix multi_db (please do!), or just remove that gem entirely.

You can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ab0ce052ba23a4cce7a84ecade0d00d9cc518ebd) where the parameters to `transaction` changed in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements, back in January 2009 (before Rails 2.3.0 was released).